# How do i host python2 and python3 applications on the same apache2 server?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, apache, debian

i' ve 2 django applications. One of them is using python2.7 and the other is python3.4 .

For the python2.7 libapache2-mod-wsgi should be installed, but for the other application libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 is required. It seems these 2 packages can' t be installed on the same system.

What would be the best way to host this 2 applications?

```
Debian: 8.6
Apache: 2.4.10-10+deb8u7
App1: python==2.7, Django==1.11.16
App2: python==3.4, Django==2.0.9
```

.

Comment: have u installed mod_wsgi to specific virtual environment?

Comment: No, i did not. Can You give me a hint how to do that? Would it help? I mean, in this case libapache2-mod-wsgi* is not required?

Comment: Activate your virtual environment and add `python3 -m manage.py pip install mod_wsgi`